# Huawei IAP - product list is empty in react native hms iap

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-iap

I implemented `react-native-hms-iap` in my react native project. I configured all the details mentioned in [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/preparedevenv-0000001050766241-V1). Also I can assure that there is no signature issue because `react-native-hms-account` `login with huawei id` is working fine in my app.

I have configured 'subscription' product in `Product Management`.
[image]

But this subscription product is not reflect in my react native app. I am getting empty `AvailableProductList`.

```
[Fri Sep 24 2021 18:22:25.188]  LOG      isEnvReady:Success
[Fri Sep 24 2021 18:22:27.192]  LOG      PurchasedRecordListView :: []
[Fri Sep 24 2021 18:22:27.323]  LOG      obtainOwnedPurchases success:: []
[Fri Sep 24 2021 18:22:27.568]  LOG      obtainOwnedPurchases success:: []
[Fri Sep 24 2021 18:22:27.572]  LOG      PurchasedRecordListView :: []
[Fri Sep 24 2021 18:22:27.652]  LOG      AvailableProductList :: {"status":{"hashCode":(hashcode),"describeContents":0,"isCanceled":false,"hasResolution":false,"isSuccess":true,"statusMessage":"success","isInterrupted":false,"statusCode":0,"errorString":"success"},"productInfoList":[],"errMsg":"success","returnCode":0}
[Fri Sep 24 2021 18:22:27.738]  LOG      AvailableProductList :: {"status":{"hashCode":(hashcode),"describeContents":0,"isCanceled":false,"hasResolution":false,"isSuccess":true,"statusMessage":"success","isInterrupted":false,"statusCode":0,"errorString":"success"},"productInfoList":[],"errMsg":"success","returnCode":0}
[Fri Sep 24 2021 18:22:27.804]  LOG      obtainOwnedPurchases success:: []
[Fri Sep 24 2021 18:22:27.855]  LOG      AvailableProductList :: {"status":{"hashCode":(hashcode),"describeContents":0,"isCanceled":false,"hasResolution":false,"isSuccess":true,"statusMessage":"success","isInterrupted":false,"statusCode":0,"errorString":"success"},"productInfoList":[],"errMsg":"success","returnCode":0}
[Fri Sep 24 2021 18:22:27.859]  LOG      PurchasedRecordListView :: []
```

[image]

What is the reason that available product list to be empty ? Is there a time period I should wait to reflect available products ?

Is there any signature should I define specifically for IAP rather than the one defined for Account ID ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have figured out the case. That was totally my mistake. I forgot to pass product sku to `HMSIapModule.obtainOwnedPurchases()` method. After I passed the product sku it is working well.